# How to add a slider to move downward in view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, cocoa-design-patterns

I am new to iOS programming, so I hope its not a stupid question to ask. I have to add ten different buttons in my view programmatically. I know how to add buttons programmatically, but my buttons won't fit within the view so some of them have to be present below the viewable height of the view, so I want to add the buttons such that the user can slide upward and downward to move across the view. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of standard UI elements [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html) provides that help handle displaying more content than the screen can display at any one time:

- [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012177)
- [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)
- [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You may benefit from some of the automatic layout and formatting provided by the `UICollectionView` but from your description it sounds as though either the `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` would be best suited for your scenario.

#### UIScrollView

The `UIScrollView` acts as the user's viewport into the underlying view it contains and provides complex panning and zooming functionality by default. It is highly configurable and you can prevent zooming functionality if you do not need it.

Just make sure to place your view inside the `UIScrollView` within Interface Builder and set the [`contentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) property. Setting a `contentSize` larger than the bounds of `UIScrollView` should enable scrolling automatically. To enable zooming have your `UIViewController` implement the [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html):

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

Then ensure to return your view in the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return theViewContainingTheButtons;
}
```

#### UITableView

The `UITableView` is specifically designed to display a list of items that can be vertically scrolled if its content is taller than the size of the view.

A `UITableView` is composed of a number of [UITableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), each of which could contain one of the buttons you wish to display. Apple's [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) covers most aspects of the `UITableView`.

#### Conclusion

The `UITableView` approach focuses specifically on what you have asked and neglects that there may be other content in the view hosting the buttons. It also means that you would have to change your existing dynamic button placement code and write new code to work with table views. In reality it's likely that the `UIScrollView` is what your looking for but I wanted to provide exposure to other UI elements you may not have been aware of that could be used to achieve what you have described.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need t use a special element, called a UIScrollView. It will handle all this automatically. Here's a link to the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIScrollView`.

Instead of adding `UIButton` to `UIView` addd then to `UIScrollView` and set `UIScrollView` `contentSize`.

Fore more help : [UIScrollView from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).